# Increase textbox value by .25

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that has a Service Time field that we want incremented by .25 upon each click of a + button.

I have the following code:

```
<script language=javascript>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#up").on('click',function(){
        $("#incdec input").val(parseFloat($("#incdec input").val())+0.25);
    });

    $("#down").on('click',function(){
        $("#incdec input").val(parseFloat($("#incdec input").val())-0.25);
    });
});
</script>
```

and the HTML part:

```
<div class="form-group" id="incdec">
    <label for="Time" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Time:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="Time" value="<%=rs.Fields.Item("Time")%>"></div>
    <button id="up">+</button>
    <button id="down">-</button>
</div>
```

This works just fine but upon clicking the + or - it increases/decreases but also submits the form it's in. I want to be able to just increase/decrease what is in the text field then submit the form with another button.

I know I am missing something stupid here!

Comment: Add type="button" to avoid default submission.

Comment: Duh!!! Thanks....lol. I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `type` attribute of a button defaults to `"submit"`. You'll want to add `type="button"` to prevent submission from occurring.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type